# Column contains column

Tags: python, pandas, contains

I would like to see whether in each row of my dataframe column A contains the value that is in column B.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["Is it 54321?", "Is it 4321?", "Is it 321?"],
                   'B': [54321, 54321, 54321]})
```

I tried:

```
df["C"] = df["A"] .str .contains(df["B"])
```

I would like:

```
'C': [1,0,0]
```

But I got:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had accepted various answers on this thread but I was having problems with them, as described here:
[Column contains column 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972214/column-contains-column-1/55972310#55972310)

Thanks to Wen-Ben for this answer:

If you do want 12 to be in 123:

```
df = df.dropna()
df['C'] = [str(y) in x for x , y in zip(df.A,df.B)]
print(df)
```

Or if you do not want 12 to be in 123:

```
df = df.dropna()
df['C'] = [str(y) in x for x , y in zip(df.A.str.split(' '),df.B)]
print(df)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56224014/column-contains-column-2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56274979/column-contains-column-3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276574/column-contains-column-4 show issues and resolve them

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
df['C']=df.A.str.contains(r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(df.B.astype(str)))).astype(int)
print(df)

              A      B  C
0  Is it 54321?  54321  1
1   Is it 4321?  54321  0
2    Is it 321?  54321  0
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with this, described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55972214/column-contains-column-1

Answer (score 0):

I found that it works as a function:

```
def fun (A,B):
    if str(B) in A:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
f = np.vectorize(fun, otypes=[float])
df["C"] = f(df['A'],df['B'])
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow, perhaps  you could include why OP made a mistake and what this does to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
df['C'] = (df['B'] == df['A'].str.rstrip('?').str.split(' ').str[-1].astype(int)) * 1
```

Comment: While this answer works, it is too specific. That is, it'll only work on strings where the intended number is the last word in the column and not if the string was "54321 is my number" for example.

Comment: Yes, the given example is misleading in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify code:

```
def fun (A,B):
    return str(B) in str(A) # Edit: A to str(A)

f = np.vectorize(fun, otypes=[int])
df["C"] = f(df['A'],df['B'])
```

Or use list comprehension:

```
df["C"] = [int(str(B) in A) for A, B in zip(df['A'],df['B'])]
```

Comment: Caveat: this method will return 'True' when 'A' is "Is it 22?" and 'B' is '2'.

Comment: @kevins_1 - yes, it test digits.

Comment: I like the simplified version of my attempt. It's the list comprehension that tests digits.