# Column contains column 2

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe. I would like to test whether, (C), on each row, the number in column (B) is in the string, column (A).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["me 123", "me-123", "1234", "me 12", "123 and"],
                   'B': [123,       123,      123,    123,     6]})
```

I would like to get:

```
         A    B  C
0   me 123  123  1
1   me-123  123  1
2     1234  123  0
3    me 12  123  0
4  123 and    6  0
```

Various approaches nearly manage this (1):

```
df['C'] = [str(y) in x for x , y in zip(df.A.str.split(' '),df.B)]

         A    B      C
0   me 123  123   True
1   me-123  123  False
2     1234  123  False
3    me 12  123  False
4  123 and    6  False
```

or (2):

```
df['C'] = [str(y) in x for x , y in zip(df.A,df.B)]

         A    B      C
0   me 123  123   True
1   me-123  123   True
2     1234  123   True
3    me 12  123  False
4  123 and    6  False
```

or (3):

```
df['C']=df.A.str.contains(r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(df.B.astype(str)))).astype(int)

         A    B  C
0   me 123  123  1
1   me-123  123  1
2     1234  123  0
3    me 12  123  0
4  123 and    6  1
```

or (4):

```
def fun (A,B):
    return str(B) in str(A)
f = np.vectorize(fun, otypes=[int])
df["C"] = f(df['A'], df['B'])

         A    B  C
0   me 123  123  1
1   me-123  123  1
2     1234  123  1
3    me 12  123  0
4  123 and    6  0
```

or (5):

```
df['A1'] = df['A'] .apply(word_tokenize)
```

Doesn't recognise - as a space. How can I get the result at the top please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vectorized way from `extract`

```
df.A.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).eq(df.B,0).astype(int)
Out[347]: 
   0
0  1
1  1
2  0
3  0
4  0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56274979/column-contains-column-3 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276574/column-contains-column-4 show issues and resolvce them.

Answer (score 1):

#### `re.findall`

```
pat = re.compile('\d+')
df.assign(C=[1 if str(b) in re.findall(pat, a) else 0 for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)])

         A    B  C
0   me 123  123  1
1   me-123  123  1
2     1234  123  0
3    me 12  123  0
4  123 and    6  0
```

---

#### `pandas.Series.str.findall`

Very similar

```
df.assign(C=df.A.str.findall(pat).str[0].eq(df.B.astype(str)).astype(int))
```