# Column contains column 3

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe. I would like to test whether, (C), on each row, the number in column (B) is in the string, column (A).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["me 123", "me-123", "1234", "me 12", "123 me"],
                   'B': [123,       123,      123,    123,     6]})
```

I can do that using extract

```
df['C'] = df.A.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(int).eq(df.B,0).astype(int)

         A    B  C
0   me 123  123  1
1   me-123  123  1
2     1234  123  0
3    me 12  123  0
4  123  me    6  0
```

However, if one of the A values does not contain a number:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["me 123", "me-123", "1234", "me 12", "123 me", "me"],
                   'B': [123,       123,      123,    123,     6,        123]})
```

Then I get:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Comment: `df.A.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).eq(df.B.astype(str)).astype(int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values `NaN`s are floats, so you can convert output to `float`s:

```
df['C'] = df.A.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(float).eq(df.B,0).astype(int)
```

Comment: I found an issue with this, found and resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56276574/column-contains-column-4/56277519#56277519